# long update statement error?

Tags: vb.net, select

I'm trying to run my system with the following codes on a button but i get a long error (I'm gonna post a link to a screenshot since I don't have enough reputation.) Thank you! https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP8DM.png
Here are the codes:

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Try
            Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE books SET Title = @titl, Author = @aut, " & _
                         "WHERE ID = " & DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & ";"

            ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
            ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

            Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
                Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, conn)

                    conn.Open()
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titl", TextBox2.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aut", TextBox3.Text)

                    If TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
                        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                        Return
                    Else
                        Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        If rowsInserted > 0 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("A record has been successfully updated!", "Updated!")
                            dtgrd()
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Failed to update record!", "Failure!")
                        End If
                    End If

                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have  a comma after `Author = @aut` remove it. It is just a simple typo, you could fix it and delete this question if you don't want to be submerged by downvotes. (As a side note, try to read about parameterized queries and why you should always use them for every value passed to the database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra comma in `Author = @aut,` your sql query, try to remove that

Replace this in your code

```
Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE books SET Title = @titl, Author = @aut " & _
   "WHERE ID = " & DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & ";"
```

And one more thing, you are checking textbox empty value in your code after opening the connection, Try to do that validation before doing anything. Then your code will be like this

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
  Try          
    If TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Then
       MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields.", "Admin", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
       Return
    End If

    Dim sqlquery As String = "UPDATE books SET Title = @titl, Author = @aut " & _
             "WHERE ID = " & DataGridView2.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString & ";"

    ' Use this form to initialize both connection and command to 
    ' avoid forgetting to set the appropriate properties....

    Using conn = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(cnString)
    Using cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlquery, conn)

     conn.Open()
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titl", TextBox2.Text)
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aut", TextBox3.Text)

     Dim rowsInserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     If rowsInserted > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("A record has been successfully updated!", "Updated!")
        dtgrd()
     Else
       MessageBox.Show("Failed to update record!", "Failure!")
     End If
    End Using
   End Using
   Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.ToString)
  End Try
End Sub
```